# Why are people in codegolf kinder than stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

I'm a new user at codegolf - (7 reputation)

So, I just made 2 questions - with 1 that's got much response and people chatting kindly,

HOWEVER, people in stack overflow are quite RUDE, giving DOWNVOTE without REASON.

What's going on?

Comment: Well... this is a place for fun, while SO is a place to be serious.

Comment: Good answer...... SO is a place that people who answers downvote the others.

Comment: Does this being a beta site have anything to do with it?

Comment: The things you *have* to understand about Stack Overflow are that it is large, and it is intentionally different from anything that came before it and many things that have come since in the way it defines "quality" for the site. And it has strong mechanisms to protect that quality. The size and popularity means there is *a lot* of stuff that drifts in and effectively attacks the site (usually without ill-intent on the part of the posters, but it is an attack none-the-less). And the users defend the site. Read the rules and follow them and you will be fine. Treat it like another forum...

Comment: @Quincunx This site being small helps. Stack Overflow was a little more forgiving when there were only 10,000 of us.

Comment: Well, although this community is way less rude than StackOverflow, don't expect that everyone will be kind here. They will not. Here, we surely do have some really rude members that do downvote and sometimes even close-vote with no mercy, so always be careful when you post questions and answers to be sure that they have a good quality and do not commit serious mistakes.

Comment: "way less rude" that is too...... i can't explain. but i think it's 99% less rude. at least i haven't seen one.

Comment: @Victor Neither downvotes nor close votes are "rude" by definition.

Comment: @dmckee They aren't rude by definition, but may be a signal of rudeness. for e.g. I already saw people close-voting a question just because it lacked the popularity-contest tag even when the question already said it was a popularity-contest. Instead of fixing a trivial simple mistake, some people prefer to close-vote. Other thing I saw was closing just for the sake of closing, choosing randomly a reason that clearly does not applies. Random downvotes from nowhere without any explanation are common too.

Answer (score 7):

We code-golfers seem to have a moral code that follows various rules, namely the following:

- Code-Golf.SE is used to help mentally challenge and educate others about techniques in code that some of us may not have come across before... Those who want to mentally challenge and educate are often not those who have a rude attitude.
- We're always happy to help someone improve their golfing score where possible, this in turn adds to the "I help you, you help me" principle we unconsciously abide to here.
- If we down-vote, we usually give a reason why, (duplicate question, possible trolling, not relevant, etc.) and we will give a reason, only because we want the question to be clear enough or understood enough for us all to participate...

Jamie, on behalf of all of us golfers, we're sorry that others in Overflow are giving you some bad attitude... I hope, and I speak on behalf of us all, that you'll prefer to hang around us more! :)

Comment: The helping attitude - I like it. I don't care MUCH about reputation, but getting -5 votes is painful.

Comment: Are you saying I'm mentally challenge?

Comment: @Fabinout, I seriously hope you're just trolling me... *sighs*

Comment: @Jamie The one good thing about this group is that we all want to be better programmers and golfers... Hell, we give coders a +1 for twisting the rules or for creative technique or for helping us shave an extra few bytes off our code...!

Just a word of advice Jamie, flesh out any code golf questions in the sandboxes in the Code Golf Meta platform here (I think we're up to Sandbox 6 or 7, or something!)

When it gets enough points in upvote, and you feel it's been fleshed out enough and solidifed with the help of some of us seasoned golfers, then post it on Code Golf Standard. :)

Comment: @WallyWest indeed

Comment: @trichoplax Providing one example of an overlap is fine... Bombarding them with six or so within the space of a few minutes can give the impression of flaming.

Comment: @trichoplax However, one of your answers showed me that my question was actually duplicating; so I withdrew the question...

Comment: @trichoplax so apologies if the delete have the impression that you had put me off the question... You hadn't... But one of the examples you provided saved me some face by ensuring that I didn't post a dupe :) it's all good!

Comment: The purpose of putting them in separate comments was to allow people to upvote any they thought particularly relevant. Since that's not how it came across, I'll make a mental note of that and avoid it from now on unless it's explained in advance. Thanks for letting me know (it makes perfect sense now you point it out). I'll delete these comments now since they don't belong here, but if there's ever anything else that jars, I'm reachable in chat and keen to know if I'm causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance - I feel better for understanding the situation. :)

Comment: @trichoplax Let's keep them here for prosperity... It kinda fits with the question, and it's a great example of why we're a lot more amicable on here... :)

Comment: That's not a bad idea - but I already deleted the first one before I saw your suggestion :(